# SSL Certificate chaining error in WAS happened intermittenly

Tags: java, openssl, websphere

I'm facing a certificate chaining error in a Websphere application server. After installing the certificate, it is working for first request and getting Certificate chaining error for the subsequent request.

Please find the log file

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl
>   could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
>     java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued
>   by EMAILADDRESS=***.**@**.com, CN=****, OU=****, O=****, ST=****, C=**
>   is not trusted; internal cause is: 
>     java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining
>   error

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons behind this error. You can [enable WAS SSL logs](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mustgather-ssl-problems-websphere-traditional) and check the trace logs or share here.

PS: It has been observed that WAS serves few incoming requests immediately after installing certificate. Experienced the same issue and the reason was installed wrong sequence of chain certificate at host side.